# Returning unique key value pairs from a config table with non-unique data where values are inhereted based on the value of other columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a config table that holds key=>value pairs where the key is nonunique with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE config
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    key varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    value text,
    siteID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES site(siteID),
    userID bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES user(userID),
    version decimal(10,4)
)
```

The table can hold multiple values associated based on a non unique key. Furthermore, there may be multiple versions of any key/value.

I would like to select a unique set of key/value pairs for a given user at a given site that follow the following rules of inheritance:
1) The max key/value needs to be returned when there are duplicate, selected, records (for example, if there are two values that don't have site or user info the value associated with the highest version number needs to be returned, otherwise the version is ignored).
2) Global values (values with no site or user info) are overridden by values that contain site info.
3) Values that contain only site info are overridden by values that contain user info
4) Values that contain only user info are overridden by values that contain user and site info

I have been doing this by selecting the above info in multiple queries like the following (pseudo code):

```
array1 = select key, value from config where userID is NULL and siteID is NULL and version = (select MAX(c.version) from config c where c.name = name)
array2 = select top 1  key, value from config where userID is NULL and siteID = @siteID and version = (select MAX(c.version) from config c where c.name = name)
array3 = select top 1  key, value from config where userID = @userID and siteID is NULL and version = (select MAX(c.version) from config c where c.name = name)
array4 = select top 1  key, value from config where userID = @userID and siteID = @siteID and version = (select MAX(c.version) from config c where c.name = name)
```

Then I take the arrays of data and do something like:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $row){
    $key = $row['key'];
    $value = $row['value'];
    $finalArray[$key] = $value;
}

foreach($array2 as $row){
    $key = $row['key'];
    $value = $row['value'];
    $finalArray[$key] = $value;
}
...etc.
```

That gives me what I want, but I have to think that there's a better way... Anyone have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
DECLARE @config TABLE
(
    ID int,
    [key] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    value varchar(10),
    siteID int,
    userID int,
    [version] INT
);

declare @userID INT = 1;

INSERT INTO @config 
(ID, [key],[value],[siteID],userID,[version])
VALUES
--Global Values
(1, 'a','a',NULL,NULL,1),
(2, 'a','b',NULL,NULL,2),
(3, 'b','c',NULL,NULL,1),
--User values Site A
(4,'x','x',1,1,1),
(5,'x','z',1,1,2),
(6,'a','z',1,1,1),
(7,'xz','xz',1,1,1),
(8,'xz','xz',1,2,1),
(9,'b','d',1,2,1);

select
*
from @config

select
*
from (
    select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            [key]
        ORDER BY
            ISNULL(siteID,-1) DESC,
            [version] DESC
    ) i,
    *
    from @config
    where
        ISNULL(userID,@userID) = @userID
) T
where
    i = 1
```